# addEventListener not supported for childBrowser on BlackBerry 10 in Phonegap app

Tags: oauth, cordova, blackberry-10, childbrowser

I am having trouble figuring out why `addEventListener` is not supported on phonegap 2.7 for BB10 app. Without this event, I am unable to use the `loadstart` and `loadstop` events to complete twitter/facebook oauth. I can see that the event handler is attached by inspecting the childbrowser window, but it never fires.

Has anyone else run into this? Is there any alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After really digging into BlackBerry Webworks there are many many similarities with Phonegap and, in fact, much of what Phonegap provides is already built into Webworks in the form of Javascript APIs that run native calls underneath.

BlackBerry Webworks natively opens external links using the `window.open` in a childBrowser window.

Thus, the solution was to remove Phonegap from the equation until Phonegap (potentially in the future) implements `addEventListener` support fo their childBrowser plugin.

After removing Phonegap, I was successfully able to use the scripts here https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Twitter-OAuth-1 and here https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/FaceBook-OAuth-2 for Twitter and Facebook OAuth successfully.